# Does there exist a Runge Fatou-Bieberbach in each Fatou-Bieberbach domain?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-dynamics, several-complex-variables

A Fatou-Bieberbach domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is a domain that is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$. A domain is said to be Runge if for each holomorphic function defined on it and each compact set in it, there exists a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to the holomorphic function on the compact set. Here is my question:

> Given a Fatou-Bieberbach domain $\Omega$, does there exists a Runge Fatou-Bieberbach domain $\Omega^\prime$ such that $\Omega^\prime \subseteq \Omega$?

It was shown by Wold in 2007 that non-Runge Fatou-Bieberbach domains exists.

Comment: It's a hard problem comparable to the one asking if for a given FB domain \Omega (can assume runge) there exists a FB domain \Omega' such that \Omega\subset \Omega' ?  Unfortunately I don't know the answer to it but you can look into https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.apde/1510843382 if it helps. In this paper there is a nice example which shows that C^n can be exhausted by non-runge FB domains.